# How django SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True affects the performance?

Tags: django

I'd like to log out user after some time (say 1h) of inactivity. To do so I can set (in django settings.py using SessionMiddleware):

- SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 3600
- SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True

However, I'm afraid of the fall of performance. Therefore, my question is: "How django SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True affects the performance?".

Comment: did you ever measure this? I suspect it's insignificant unless you have >3K simultaneous users when it'll make sense to switch the session engine from db to cache.

Answer (score 6):

cf Django docs : "To change this default behavior, set the SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST setting to True. When set to True, Django will save the session to the database on every single request."

If you're using a relationnal database as session backend, this will launch an UPDATE or INSERT on session table for each request by every user.
Most databases are mainly optimized for read operations, so, having so much write operations will soon degrade your server performance and limit user concurrency

Comment: I was aware that it requires database operations (because I read part of documentation you quoted). I also suspected that it might cause performance issues, but I was wondering how significant.